# migration requires an FQDN

Tags: migration, live

How to solve internal error hostname on destination resolved to localhost, but migration requires an FQDN?

I've tried to migrate Qemu to kvmmode2 but i got that message.

My /etc/hosts is:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain    localhost    localhost4
::1   kvmmode1.localdomain       kvmmode1     localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
192.168.10.5    kvmmode1.localdomain   kvmmode1
192.168.10.6    kvmmode2.localdomain   kvmmode2
```

Comment: Can you clarify what have you tried and what is not working?

Comment: @Jose Gomez I use virtual manager to migrate kvm virtual machine when i add connection with hypervisor KVM and hostname kvmmode2.localdomain i got this message "unable to migrate guest: internal error hostname on destination resolved to localhost, but migration requires an FQDN"